# paracol doesn't work inside tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, paracol

I am trying to get a paracol environment to work with a tcolorbox environment so that I can get a nice border around part of the text.

However, it seems like that is not possible.

Minimal code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \lipsum[1-2]
        \switchcolumn
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{paracol}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Is this possible or should I try using a different package?

Comment: You can put multiple `tcolorbox` inside `paracol`, which might or might not meet your needs.

Comment: You can also place `parcolumns` inside a `tcolorbox`.

Comment: One of pracol's abilities is to write more than one page at a time, which can only be done in outer par mode.

Comment: I should look into `parcolumns` since I want the "non-equal" part of `paracol` but not the "multi page" part.

Answer (score 2):

You can use here a tabular environment or `multicol`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \lipsum[1-2]
        \columnbreak
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{multicols}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

But why not only `tcolorbox`?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside,sidebyside align=top, lower separated=false]
\lipsum[1-2]
\tcblower
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I specifically want two columns of text where the right one is narrower than the left. I don't think either of these proposals do that. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @SebastianMalton  Do you think the same after add  `lefthand width=.6\linewidth` to  `tcolorbox` ?

Answer (score 1):

Another environment that does work inside a `tcolorbox` is `parcolumns`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{parcolumns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    \begin{parcolumns}{2}
        \colchunk{\lipsum[1-2]}
        \colchunk{\lipsum[1]}
        \colplacechunks
    \end{parcolumns}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I will look into this. Does `parcolumns` have a way specify the column ratio like `paracol` does?.

Comment: @SebastianMalton Unfortunately, no. And putting `paracol` inside a `minipage` does not work either.